# Page title not changed when using @RenderPage

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm using `@RenderPage` to reuse the code across two similar pages. Each of the two pages consists of just `@RenderPage`:

```
@RenderPage("~/Views/PathToImplementation.cshtml", new { paramsListHere })
```

the code reused (inside `PathToImplementation.cshtml`) uses `ViewBag.Title` to set the page title:

```
ViewBag.Title = somethingUseful;
```

The problem is changing `ViewBag.Title` from inside the reused code has no effect on the original page - nothing happens.

How do I change the title of a page from the code called by `@RenderPage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like when `RenderPage` is used the `ViewBag` is duplicated and the copy is passed into the page which `RenderPage` renders and there's no way back. So the cleanest way I've found so far is passing a reference to the page that calls `RenderPage`. Something like this:

```
//calling page
@RenderPage( PathToPage.cshtml, new { ParentPage = this } )

//PathToPage.cshtml
@{  WebViewPage parentPage = PageData["ParentPage"];
    parentPage.ViewBag.Title = blahblahblhah;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your title is inside `PathToImplementation.cshtml` and using a parameters to set the title within `PathToImplementation.cshtml`, your parameters should be accessed using `PageData`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.renderpage%28v=vs.99%29.aspx).

Here is an [example](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/code-snippets/razor-snippets/@renderpage-with-args)

Ex;

```
   @PageData[index]; //Or 
   @PageData["title"];
```

Comment: Does this imply I have to pass a reference to the original page into the reused page?

Comment: Say `@RenderPage("~/Views/PathToImplementation.cshtml", "PageTitle", "Description")`. Then `@PageData[0] --> "PageTitle"` and `@PageData[1] --> "Description"` within `PathToImplementation.cshtml`.

Comment: Then how do I change the page title from the reused page?

Comment: Pls take look at the example link. It gives a better idea.